# Magento 2 : X-Magento-Tags missing form header

Tags: magento2.2

I have configured varnished cached form admin and also apply a configuration in a server but after all setting in response header **"X-Magento-Tags"** is missing.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 07 Feb 2018 09:24:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=uaihth5qld485ofuniut5ios86; expires=Wed, 07-Feb-2018 10:23:59 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=xxx; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: store=default; expires=Thu, 07-Feb-2019 09:23:59 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: searchReport-log=0; path=/
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
Expires: Tue, 07 Feb 2017 09:23:59 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow
```

Magento version 2.2.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After lot's of debugging, i got solution
I have written **cacheble="false" into default.xml** and that's creating an issue so I just removed cacheble="false" form default.xml

**Reason for an issue.**
Magento First checked that all block are cacheable and configuration is on or not but due to **cacheble="false" into default.xml** below function return false so X-Magento-Tags are never added to the header.

```
$subject->isCacheable()
```

vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Layout/LayoutPlugin.php

```
 public function afterGetOutput(\Magento\Framework\View\Layout $subject, $result)
{
    if ($subject->isCacheable() && $this->config->isEnabled()) {
        $tags = [];
        foreach ($subject->getAllBlocks() as $block) {
            if ($block instanceof \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface) {
                $isEsiBlock = $block->getTtl() > 0;
                $isVarnish = $this->config->getType() == \Magento\PageCache\Model\Config::VARNISH;
                if ($isVarnish && $isEsiBlock) {
                    continue;
                }
                $tags = array_merge($tags, $block->getIdentities());
            }
        }
        $tags = array_unique($tags);
        $this->response->setHeader('X-Magento-Tags', implode(',', $tags));
    }
    return $result;
}
```